# Weird bug with fopen() modifying char array? [C language]

Tags: c, arrays, char, fopen

So `main()` is supposed to extract all the filenames in my current directory and put them into an array, then check if the files are regular files. Then, it passes all the regular files into `fun()`.

The problem is that, even though `main()` passes in a valid array, some elements of the array (not all of them) are deleted after it is passed into `fun()`

```
//Output of command line before array is passed into fun()
reg 0: a.out
reg 1: myar
reg 2: proj2.tex
reg 3: myar.c
reg 4: ar
reg 5: makefile
reg 6: new.c
reg 7: newfile.txt
reg 8: newar

//Output of command line after passed into fun()
reg 0:
reg 1:
reg 2:
reg 3: myar.c
reg 4:
reg 5:
reg 6:
reg 7: newfile.txt
reg 8: newar
```

The extremely weird thing is that, if i remove the `fopen()` statement in `fun()`, then nothing goes wrong. Could it be that `fopen()` is modifying something it shouldn't be? Code provided below:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 #include <dirent.h>
  4 #include <sys/stat.h>
  5
  6 void fun(char* arfile, char** filenames, int file_count)
  7 {
  8     int i;
  9     FILE* f = fopen("text.txt", "a");
 10
 11     for (i=0;i<file_count;i++){
 12         printf("reg %d: %s\n",i,filenames[i]);
 13         fflush(stdout);
 14     }
 15
 16     fclose(f);
 17 }
 18
 19
 20 int main (int argc, char** argv)
 21 {
 22     struct stat s;
 23     DIR *d;
 24     struct dirent *dir;
 25     int i, file_count = 0, reg_count = 0;
 26     char **filenames, **regular_files;
 27     char *arfile;
 28
 29     if (argc != 2)
 30         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 31     else
 32         arfile = argv[1];
 33
 34     d = opendir(".");
 35
 36     while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL){
 37         file_count++;
 38     }
 39
 40     closedir(d);
 41     filenames     = malloc(file_count*sizeof(char*));
 42     regular_files = malloc(file_count*sizeof(char*));
 43
 44     d = opendir(".");
 45
 46     for (i = 0; (dir = readdir(d)) != NULL; i++){
 47         filenames[i] = dir->d_name;
 48     }
 49
 50     closedir(d);
 51
 52     for (i = 2; i < file_count ; i++){
 53         if (stat(filenames[i], &s) == -1) {
 54             perror("Unable to read file stats");
 55             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 56         }
 57
 58         if (S_ISREG(s.st_mode)){
 59             regular_files[reg_count] = filenames[i];
 60             reg_count++;
 61         }

 62     }
 63
 64     for (i=0;i<reg_count;i++){
 65         printf("reg %d: %s\n",i,regular_files[i]);
 66         fflush(stdout);
 67     }
 68     fun(arfile, regular_files, reg_count);
 69
 70     free(filenames);
 71     free(regular_files);
 72     return 0;
 73 }
 74
```

Comment: You can't hang onto `dir->d_name` after further `readdir()` calls, and certainly not after `closedir()`.  You'll have to copy it with `strdup()` or something.

Comment: this line: 'filenames[i] = dir->d_name;'  has two problems:  1) this will not copy the name, only the address of dir->d_name.   suggest strcpy( filenames[i], dir->d_name);'    2) the malloc() only allocated an array of pointers to char.  Each filenames[i] actually points nowhere in particular. (should initialize them to all NULL to make the calls to free() simple)  suggest: filenames[i] = malloc( strlen( dir->d_name)+1);    Of course, every call to malloc needs to followed by a check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding this line: 'exit(EXIT_FAILURE);'  Just because one file cannot be 'stat'ed, does not mean that the other files cannot be 'stat'ed.  Suggest the logic work around this problem rather than abruptly exiting the program.  Strongly suggest reading the man page 2 regarding 'stat'

Comment: the 'fun()' function (terrible/meaningless function name) does nothing but echo some garbage to stdout.  the file 'text.txt' (which is opened in 'append' mode) receives nothing.  the parameter: 'arfile' is not used.

Comment: suggest stepping through the code with a debugger so you can see where things are going wrong.   Also, why bother with having a parameter on the command line?  That parameter is never really used.

Answer (score 1):

`readdir` is non-reenterable function -- it holds temporary static buffer which is **overwritten** after each iteration, so data referred by `dir->d_name` becomes invalid. You need to copy them, i.e. with `strdup()`:

```
for (i = 0; (dir = readdir(d)) != NULL; i++) {     
     filenames[i] = strdup(dir->d_name);
}
```

And don't forget to free allocated strings:

```
for (i = 0; i < file_count; i++) {     
     free(filenames[i]);
}
```

You may also look at reenterable functions like `readdir_r`, but they are not much helpful in your case.

Comment: Oh that makes sense! Thanks very much, you just saved me another two hours